# Improper output using libusb

Tags: c, linux, libusb

I have made a program using libusb. I doubt if the output is correct as all the entries show the same vendor and product id. Following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

void print_devices(libusb_device *dev)
{
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    struct libusb_config_descriptor *config;

    const struct libusb_interface *inter;
    const struct libusb_interface_descriptor *interdesc;
    const struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor *endpointdesc;

    int ret;
    int i,j,k;

    if(ret<0)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr,"error in getting device descriptor\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Number of possible configs is %d\n",desc.bNumConfigurations);
    printf("Vendor: %d\n",desc.idVendor);
    printf("Product ID: %d\n",desc.idProduct);

    libusb_get_config_descriptor(dev, 0, &config);

    printf("Interface: %d\n", config->bNumInterfaces);
    printf("\n\n"); 
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    libusb_device **devs;
    libusb_context *context = NULL;

    size_t list;
    size_t i;

    int ret,temp;

    ret = libusb_init(&context);

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("libusb_init");
        exit(1);
    }

    list = libusb_get_device_list(context, &devs);

    if(list < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in getting device list\n");
        libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
        libusb_exit(context);
        exit(1);
    }

    temp=(int)list;
    printf("\n%d devices found\n\n",temp);

    for(i=0;i<temp;i++)
    {
        //print devices
        print_devices(devs[i]);
    }

    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
    libusb_exit(context);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my output:

```
anubhav@anubhav-Inspiron-3421:~/Desktop/usb$ ./usbtest

9 devices found

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 2

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 4

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1

Number of possible configs is 103
Vendor: 0
Product ID: 0
Interface: 1
```

this is what lsusb shows:

```
anubhav@anubhav-Inspiron-3421:~/Desktop/usb$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:812c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Need help to locate the error(if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line must have been accidentally skipped somewhere... I suggest you add the following line, otherwise `ret` is unitialized :

```
int ret;
int i,j,k;

ret = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);//this line !
if(ret<0)
{   
    fprintf(stderr,"error in getting device descriptor\n");
    return;
}
```

To compare the output to the one of `lsusb`, change for `%x` to print `idVendor` and `idProduct` using hexadecimal format.

```
printf("Vendor: %x\n",desc.idVendor);
printf("Product ID: %x\n",desc.idProduct);
```

The following question [libusb semi-working, but libusb_device_descriptor undeclared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458444/libusb-semi-working-but-libusb-device-descriptor-undeclared) was helpful to find the missing line. And this one helped me linking `libusb` [Libusb undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050482/libusb-undefined-reference-to)  it advices to compile by `gcc main.c -o main -lusb-1.0`.

Comment: Yes, the line you have  mentioned was supposed to be added. I got the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: is there any piece of information about a usb device that I can get through libusb but not lsusb command?

Comment: `lsusb` seems to be based on `libusb`...If you type `lsusb -v`, you will get a lot of data about usb devices. The way you use it in your program is cleaner and much more elegant than calling something like `system` and parsing a file...I can't tell you if `libusb` is able to deliver more data than `lsusb`.