# How to get USB port from USB device name?

Tags: c, usb

I want to create a small program, where I read from a serial port in C. Up to this point it works fine and does exactly what I want it to do.

But how can I get the port (/dev/*something*) from the device name?
Using `lsusb`, I for example got this entry for my keyboard:

```
Bus 020 Device 007: ID 24ae:2000 24ae RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device
```

On the right hand side I get something like "RAPOO Device", which is the vendor or name of the device. Can I get the port, where that device is currently connected to ***with any C function on Linux***?

Edit:
Check this example [Improper output using libusb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083184/improper-output-using-libusb) for a possible solution!

Comment: No, I need a function in the programming language C!

Comment: Check out the source code for lsusb: https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb.c

Comment: I retract my duplicate, the right one can be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083184/improper-output-using-libusb but I cannot vote again for it

Comment: Okay, well that duplicate works better for me. I want to pass my program a string representing the usb name. Then the program should search where the port / mounting point is.